# SQL - Switching on two different dates in same row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a fairly simple query:

```
SELECT invoice_id WHERE employee_id = 'XXXX' AND customer_id = 'YYYY'
    AND [date] < '2012-06-27';
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to switch the column [date], based upon a condition, in this case which is smaller or earliest.

In other words, something like

```
SELECT invoice_id WHERE employee_id = 'XXXX' AND customer_id = 'YYYY'
    AND (IF(time_created <= transaction_date)) time_created < '2012-06-27' ELSE 
        transaction_date > '2012-06-27');
```

So a query that uses the earliest date in the row by comparing two columns(though it may seem that time_created should always be earliest, that is not the case here). If not, I can split the query into two, but I'm wondering if it can be done in one.

Comment: something like this? http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?61,65636,66549

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT invoice_id WHERE employee_id = 'XXXX' AND customer_id = 'YYYY'
AND IF(time_created <= transaction_date, time_created < '2012-06-27', transaction_date > '2012-06-27');
```

or ANSI SQL solution:

```
SELECT invoice_id WHERE employee_id = 'XXXX' AND customer_id = 'YYYY'
AND CASE WHEN time_created <= transaction_date
         THEN time_created < '2012-06-27'
         ELSE transaction_date > '2012-06-27'
    END
```

Comment: ANSI SQL does not allow a condition inside a case like that.  It has to be something like `case when ... then 1 end = 1`, not `case when ... then 1=1 end`.  Your first query is probably the best in MySQL, +1

Comment: According to the http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt `then` clause is a `<result> ::= <result expression> | NULL` and `time_created < '2012-06-27'` is an expression, that returns boolean

Answer (score 3):

You could use a double condition, like:

```
and  (
    time_created <= transaction_date and time_created < '2012-06-27' or
    time_created > transaction_date and transaction_date > '2012-06-27'
)
```

Comment: This would fail if `time_created` can be null

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming `time_created` and `transaction_date` are not nullable